# Regex to highlight percentiles above 85% red in a text file

Tags: regex, grep

If anyone is confident in their regex abilities:

Can you help me color all of the percentiles above 85% red. The format would be xxx% where xxx is 86-100%. I'm looking to use a grep command like:

```
grep -P --colour=always '(?:^|(?<=[\\, ;\-\+\*\/]))[-+]?[0-9]*[\.eE]?[0-9]+|$'
```

This one highlights every number red which is not what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help! I'm at a new job and am trying to go above and beyond.

Comment: Try `grep -P '(?<![^\\, ;+*/-])[-+]?\b(?:8[6-9]|9[0-9]|100)%'` or just `grep -P '[-+]?\b(?:8[6-9]|9[0-9]|100)%'`

Comment: Thank you!! This is beautiful

Comment: What would I change if I still want it to show everything else? This just returns the lines where that occurs.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? To show everything else, you do not need any grep or regex.

Comment: I just needed to do a grep -B 3 to get the lines before! Got it working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
grep -P '[-+]?\b(?:8[6-9]|9[0-9]|100)%' file
```

See the PCRE [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5zz10V/1) (`-P` enables the PCRE regex engine).

*Details*:

- `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+` char
- `\b` - a word boundary (there can be no letter, digit or `_` immediately to the left of the current location, since the next char is a digit, i.e.  a word char)
- `(?:8[6-9]|9[0-9]|100)` - `8` followed with `6`, `7`, `8` or `9` or `9` followed with any one digit or `100`
- `%` - a `%` char.